# Parse ESXI vim-cmd hostsvc/autostartmanager/get_autostartseq to get each VM stopDelay param

Tags: bash, awk, sed, esxi

I have shutdown script for each ESXI when the UPS is on battery. I need to make this script better to read "stopDelay" which can be set in ESXI host UI. This value can be found in console with command vim-cmd. **I need script which will return "stopDelay" for desired VM ID as input param.**

e.g.:

```
[root@localhost:~] vim-cmd hostsvc/autostartmanager/get_autostartseq

(vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) [
   (vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) {
      key = 'vim.VirtualMachine:1',
      startOrder = 1,
      startDelay = 10,
      waitForHeartbeat = "systemDefault",
      startAction = "powerOn",
      stopDelay = 13,
      stopAction = "systemDefault"
   },
   (vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) {
      key = 'vim.VirtualMachine:2',
      startOrder = 2,
      startDelay = -1,
      waitForHeartbeat = "systemDefault",
      startAction = "powerOn",
      stopDelay = 5,
      stopAction = "systemDefault"
   },
   (vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) {
      key = 'vim.VirtualMachine:3',
      startOrder = 3,
      startDelay = -1,
      waitForHeartbeat = "systemDefault",
      startAction = "powerOn",
      stopDelay = -1,
      stopAction = "systemDefault"
   }
]
```

How to parse this output to get VM ID and its stopDelay value?
e.q.:

```
./getVMStopDelay 1 => 13
./getVMStopDelay 2 => 5
./getVMStopDelay 3 => -1
```

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: [tag:bash] is available on ESXi?

Comment: @user1934428 I was trying to solve it with awk and sed. Unfortunatelly without success. Please let these comments away..

Comment: `./getVMStopDelay 1 => 13` creates a file named `13`.

Comment: I don't see in your post any `awk` or `sed`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
(vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) [
   (vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) {
      key = 'vim.VirtualMachine:1',
      startOrder = 1,
      startDelay = 10,
      waitForHeartbeat = "systemDefault",
      startAction = "powerOn",
      stopDelay = 13,
      stopAction = "systemDefault"
   },
   (vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) {
      key = 'vim.VirtualMachine:2',
      startOrder = 2,
      startDelay = -1,
      waitForHeartbeat = "systemDefault",
      startAction = "powerOn",
      stopDelay = 5,
      stopAction = "systemDefault"
   },
   (vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo) {
      key = 'vim.VirtualMachine:3',
      startOrder = 3,
      startDelay = -1,
      waitForHeartbeat = "systemDefault",
      startAction = "powerOn",
      stopDelay = -1,
      stopAction = "systemDefault"
   }
]
```

then

```
awk 'index($0,"(vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo)")>1{cnt+=1}/stopDelay/{sub(/,/,"");print "./getVMStopDelay",cnt,"=>",$NF}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
./getVMStopDelay 1 => 13
./getVMStopDelay 2 => 5
./getVMStopDelay 3 => -1
```

Explanation: I use [`index`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to detect line where `(vim.host.AutoStartManager.AutoPowerInfo)` is indented, i.e. start is after 1st character, if it is so I do increase `cnt` value by 1. When I find line with `stopDelay` I replace `,` using empty string i.e. delete it and print in format compliant with your requirements using value of `cnt` and content of last field (`$NF`).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)*

Comment: Thank you. I have modified code from your answer and it works nice. I was parsing text with awk wrong and you took me to right direction.